# Calling a REST service inside another REST service (Apache Camel)

Tags: web-services, rest, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have implemented following APIS using CXF REST Service and Apache Camel.

- http://localhost:9090/api/compute
- http://localhost:9091/api/listAction

Both these APIs are of `POST` type, and will accept `json` input.

- First API will take a single `json` object and perform some actions on that, and will return updated `json`.
- Second API is supposed to take a `json` array of objects of previous type and call first API for each object in array.

Here you can find my camel route for second API.

```
<route id="listActionRoute" customId="true" startupOrder="1">
    <from uri="direct-vm:listAction-service"/>
    <log message="Mapping done ${body[0]} ${body[0].size}"/>
    <setBody>
        <simple>${body[0]}</simple>
    </setBody>
    <loop copy="true">
        <simple>${body.size}</simple>
        <setBody>
            <simple>${body[${property.CamelLoopIndex}]}</simple>
        </setBody>

        <marshal>
            <json library="Jackson"/>
        </marshal>

        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
            <constant>POST</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <recipientList>
            <simple>http://localhost:9090/api/compute</simple>
        </recipientList>
        <log message="Response is ${body}"/>
    </loop>
    <marshal>
        <json library="Jackson"/>
    </marshal>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelCxfRsUsingHttpAPI">
        <constant>TRUE</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <setHeader headerName="Accept">
        <constant>application/json</constant>
    </setHeader>
</route>
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error while calling the first API inside the camel route shared here.

The stack trace is as follows:

> Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-localhost-35741-1477139495717-17-3
>   on ExchangeId: ID-localhost-35741-1477139495717-17-4). Exhausted after
>   delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Invalid uri: /api/listAction/api/listAction. If you are
>   forwarding/bridging http endpoints, then enable the bridgeEndpoint
>   option on the endpoint: Endpoint[http://localhost:9090/api/compute]
>
> Message History
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor
>   Elapsed (ms) [listActionRoute   ] [listActionRoute   ]
>   [direct-vm://listAction-service
>   ] [       957] [demoRoute         ] [log39             ] [log
>   ] [        70] [demoRoute         ] [recipientList17   ]
>   [recipientList[simple{direct-vm:${header.operationName}-service}]
>   ] [       887] [listActionRoute   ] [log35             ] [log
>   ] [       846] [listActionRoute   ] [setBody15         ]
>   [setBody[simple{${body[0]}}]
>   ] [         1] [listActionRoute   ] [bean10            ]
>   [bean[com.demo.service.DemoService@638f6584]
>   ] [        12] [listActionRoute   ] [loop8             ]
>   [loop[simple{${body.size}}]
>   ] [        23] [listActionRoute   ] [log36             ] [log
>   ] [         1] [listActionRoute   ] [setBody16         ]
>   [setBody[simple{${body[${property.CamelLoopIndex}]}}]
>   ] [         2] [listActionRoute   ] [log37             ] [log
>   ] [         1] [listActionRoute   ] [marshal17         ]
>   [marshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JsonDataFormat@74104d19]
>   ] [         2] [listActionRoute   ] [setHeader26       ]
>   [setHeader[CamelHttpMethod]
>   ] [         1] [listActionRoute   ] [recipientList16   ]
>   [recipientList[simple{http://localhost:9090/api/compute}]
>   ] [        15]
>
> Exchange
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Exchange[     Id                  ID-localhost-35741-1477139495717-17-4
>     ExchangePattern     InOut   Headers
>   {Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,
>   accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.5,
>   breadcrumbId=ID-localhost-35741-1477139495717-18-1,
>   CamelAcceptContentType=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,
>   CamelCxfMessage={org.apache.cxf.message.MessageFIXED_PARAMETER_ORDER=false,
>   org.apache.cxf.resource.method=public java.lang.String
>   com.demo.endpoints.DemoResource.listAction(java.util.List),
>   http.base.path=http://localhost:9091, HTTP.REQUEST=(POST
>   /api/listAction)@585231269 org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request@22e1eba5,
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.Destination=org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination@26de7b21,
>   HTTP.CONFIG=null, jaxrs.template.parameters={FINAL_MATCH_GROUP=[/]},
>   org.apache.cxf.message.Message.QUERY_STRING=null,
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.OperationResourceInfoStack=[org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.MethodInvocationInfo@63dce19e],
>   org.apache.cxf.message.Message.ENCODING=ISO-8859-1,
>   HTTP.CONTEXT=ServletContext@o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler{,null},
>   Content-Type=application/json,
>   org.apache.cxf.security.SecurityContext=org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$2@7f64c12c,
>   org.apache.cxf.continuations.ContinuationProvider=org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.continuations.JettyContinuationProvider@5275a1a6,
>   org.apache.cxf.message.Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS={Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8],
>   accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate], Accept-Language=[en-US,en;q=0.5],
>   connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[120],
>   content-type=[application/json], Host=[localhost:9091],
>   User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0]},
>   org.apache.cxf.request.url=http://localhost:9091/api/listAction,
>   Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,
>   org.apache.cxf.request.uri=/api/listAction,
>   org.apache.cxf.message.Message.PATH_INFO=/api/listAction,
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.https.CertConstraints=null,
>   HTTP.RESPONSE=HTTP/1.1 200
>
> , org.apache.cxf.request.method=POST,
>   org.apache.cxf.async.post.response.dispatch=true,
>   org.apache.cxf.message.Message.IN_INTERCEPTORS=[org.apache.cxf.transport.https.CertConstraintsInterceptor@55180f7],
>   HTTP_CONTEXT_MATCH_STRATEGY=stem, http.service.redirection=null,
>   path_to_match_slash=/api/listAction,
>   org.apache.cxf.configuration.security.AuthorizationPolicy=null},
>   CamelCxfRsOperationResourceInfoStack=[org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.MethodInvocationInfo@63dce19e],
>   CamelCxfRsResponseClass=class java.lang.String,
>   CamelCxfRsResponseGenericType=class java.lang.String,
>   CamelHttpCharacterEncoding=ISO-8859-1, CamelHttpMethod=POST,
>   CamelHttpPath=/api/listAction, CamelHttpUri=/api/listAction,
>   CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0,
>   connection=keep-alive, Content-Length=120,
>   Content-Type=application/json, Host=localhost:9091,
>   operationName=listAction, User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux
>   x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0}     BodyType
>   byte[]    Body                {"name":"Mr XYZ Mr","salary":100.0} ]
>
> Stacktrace
>
> **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri: /api/listAction/api/listAction. If you are forwarding/bridging http
>   endpoints, then enable the bridgeEndpoint option on the endpoint:
>   Endpoint[http://localhost:9090/api/compute]**

Can anyone help me to understand, why am I getting this error and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the headers are getting mixed up. I think you can solve it by clearing the headers something similar to `.removeHeaders("*")` between each call.